# DB architecture advise for reporting dashboard

Tags: database, database-administration, emr, amazon-emr

I'm trying to build a reporting system but having issues with slow queries, would love to hear your advise on it:
Which DB (or any other big data solution) should I use in order to support:
- ETL every 15 minutes
- 300M rows every day
- Queries from a web application should return in ~20 seconds.

Currently I'm using EMR with date partition on ORC tables but even when running a query with group by on 1 dimensions and sums the measures, it takes it more than 1 minute.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried presto ? It offers faster adhoc querying.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some great discussion on Database + Search tier from AWS ReInvent:

https://youtu.be/K7o5OlRLtvU?t=1574

What Data Store Should I Use ?

[image]